# <css-doodle> uses ± in one of their examples

Tags: javascript, css, css-doodle

On the [css-doodle](https://css-doodle.com/) site one of their first examples uses a '±' symbol like this:

```css
/* 10 PRINT */

@grid: 16 / 320px;

@size: 1px calc(141.4% + 1px);
transform: rotate(@p(±45deg));
background: #AEACFB;
margin: auto;
```

I've never seen this used before in JS or CSS so I'm just wondering if this is some feature unique to css-doodle, or is this actually usable in either CSS or JS?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty in CSS, but it looks like thats a custom feature specific to `css-doodle` (implemented by whatever `@p` is).

Answer (score 2):

It's a common pattern to use `+` and `-` for the same value. So `@p(±45deg)` is a shorthand for `@p(+45deg, -45deg)` or `@p(-45deg, +45deg)`.

This is a feature that is specific in css-doodle but not documented.

Answer (score 1):

`@p` is an alias of `@pick`

> Randomly pick a value from the given list. <sup>[ref](https://css-doodle.com/#function-@pick)</sup>

So that example with either pick `45deg` or `-45deg`

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/css-doodle@0.15.3/css-doodle.min.js"></script>

Only 45deg
<css-doodle>
  @grid: 16 / 320px;
  @size: 1px calc(141.4% + 1px);
  transform: rotate(@p(45deg));
  background: #AEACFB;
  margin: auto;
</css-doodle>

only -45deg
<css-doodle>
  @grid: 16 / 320px;
  @size: 1px calc(141.4% + 1px);
  transform: rotate(@p(-45deg));
  background: #AEACFB;
  margin: auto;
</css-doodle>

both 45deg and -45deg
<css-doodle>
  @grid: 16 / 320px;
  @size: 1px calc(141.4% + 1px);
  transform: rotate(@p(±45deg));
  background: #AEACFB;
  margin: auto;
</css-doodle>
```